# When I boot my Ubuntu appears a message: /dev/sda clean

Tags: development

I'm new in Linux and I don't know what I need to do in this screen or if it's an error.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

Every time you boot your computer, Ubuntu performs a quick, automated scan of the filesystem on your hard drive (`/dev/sda`) to make sure everything's OK. The `clean` part of the message means everything is, in fact, OK, and no problems were found. Unless it's causing undue delays in booting, it's not an issue, and it's nothing to worry about!

Comment: The problem is ,before that message, Ubuntu don't boot, I don't know if I need to wait more time to Ubuntu's boot